# Unit test with Mock Object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

```
public class Product
{
    public int Sum(int a, int b) => a +b;
}

[TestMethod]
public void SumTest()
{
    var moc = new Mock<Product>();
    moc.Setup(m => m.Sum(1, 1)).Returns(3);
}
```

How to Mock from class(not interface or not virtual function) can Setup(...).Returns(...)?
I can not add the object or class to the interface or virtual in this case.

otherwise, I can not make fake date with Mock. How can I make fake data? **but can not change type class and method**. Please give me some advice.
Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Moq to alter the behavior of a nonvirtual method on a class like this.

The way Moq works is similar to inheriting from the type (class or interface) mocked, and then overriding the member (method) in question. That is not possible in this case.

To use Moq, the mocked type must be either an interface or a nonstatic nonsealed class, and the member must be either `abstract` or `virtual` (including `override` that is not `sealed override`). There are also limitation on the access levels, but that is not a problem in your case where both the class and the method are `public`.

Comment: So I can not make fake data via Mock in this case. If this case need to test for Database, but I can not access to the DB. how can I test it?

Comment: Good question. It appears you have a hard [dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) on the class `Product`. Such a design makes it hard to test. But you do seem to have a way to inject your `Mock<Product>`? It is just that if it has to be the class-type `Product`, and it uses the nonvirtual method `Sum`, and then the implementation of `Sum` is locked, and there is no way you could come with an "alternative" `Product` where `Sum` has a different behavior.

Comment: yes correct. my case, I can do it except change type of class and method. hmm, so I only can try to make fake data :(

Comment: There could be other tools than Moq capable of mocking "final" members (i.e. members not allowing overrides).

Comment: You could look into something like [Fody Virtuosity](https://github.com/Fody/Virtuosity) to make all your members virtual, but honestly I'd just try to make the code you want to test, well, testable.

Answer (score 1):

As always another layer of abstraction can help here :)

```
public interface IProduct 
{
   int Sum(int a, int b);
}

public class ProductWrapper: IProduct
{
    readonly Product product;
    ProductWrapper(Product product) => this.product = product;
    public int Sum(int a, int b) => product.Sum(a, b);
}
```

With these in your hand you can start depending on abstraction (`IProduct`) rather than implementation (`Product` or `ProductWrapper`) which allows you mock your dependency.

```
//Arrange
var productMock = new Mock<IProduct>();
productMock.Setup(m => m.Sum(1, 1)).Returns(3);

var sut = new SUT(productMock.Object);

//Act
//...
```

Comment: I tried to make the same class, but when mock object was set a result, then how the Product class get the result?
var sut = new ProductWrapper(productMock.Object); <= IProduct vs Product ?

Comment: @denis No no no. You should mock your dependencies in unit tests. In your question the `Product` is the dependency which is used by another class (`SUT`). In my example the `IProduct` is the dependency of the other class which is mockable since it is an interface. Does it make sense?

Comment: Good idea. Instead of answering the question, you show what the asker could do. And @denis, the idea is that `ProductWrapper` is just as inflexible as `Product` itself, but `IProduct` is entirely open to any implementation, including a mock, since it is an interface without method body.